# The best overloaded method match for table (string, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting this error while parsing the values to a dataset "GetSubmitDataBy". I'm taking the values from 2 dropdownlist consisting state and cluster and 2 text boxes taking start date and end date.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RunTimeDSTableAdapters.tbl_runtime_reportTableAdapter state = new RunTimeDSTableAdapters.tbl_runtime_reportTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate);
    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate);
    dt1.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
    dt2.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
    dt = state.GetSubmitDataBy(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, dt1, dt2, DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

And the signature of the GetSubmitDataBy is:

```
public virtual RunTimeDS.tbl_runtime_reportDataTable GetSubmitDataBy(string Cluster, string startDate, string endDate, string State) {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[2];
            if ((Cluster == null)) {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Cluster));
            }
            if ((startDate == null)) {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(startDate));
            }
            if ((endDate == null)) {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = ((string)(endDate));
            }
            if ((State == null)) {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[3].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            else {
                this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[3].Value = ((string)(State));
            }
            RunTimeDS.tbl_runtime_reportDataTable dataTable = new RunTimeDS.tbl_runtime_reportDataTable();
            this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what's GetSubmitDataBy signature?

Comment: GetSubmitDataBy is a dataset

Comment: `GetSubmitDataBy` is a method and it's not part of `DataSet` class (it's on `tbl_runtime_reportTableAdapter` or it's extension method for that). Post its signature otherwise hardly you can have any help. Put cursor in the middle of that word and press F12 then copy method signature.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Here is the signature that you were asking for. I'm adding it with the question.

Comment: dt1.ToString() has to be saved in a string (as Alexander suggested). Moreover for that signature you're also missing one parameter...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I've done as Alexander suggested but not getting any output on the grid view. I'm sorry I did not understand which parameter am I missing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt1.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
dt2.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

do nothing!
you have to correct line

```
dt = state.GetSubmitDataBy(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString(), dt1.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY"), dt2.ToString("MM/DD/YYYY"), DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: How do you know `GetSubmitDataBy` overloads? Even OP doesn't provide this information.

Comment: You're right about those two lines but this is another error and it doesn't answer his question

Comment: GetSubmitDataBy is a dataset method.

Comment: at least one overload of the method we know - in the title of the question (string, string, string, string).

Comment: @Alexander The line suggested by you took away the error though but it is not showing the result on the grid view after clicking on the submit button.